# Sendgrid Azure PHP

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid

I am a newbie to php, azure, and sendgrid.

here is some code I found that I am trying to use for the html form.

```html
<!-- BEGINNING OF CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="section-page-landing" id="contact">
   <div class="inner-section">
    <div class="contain">
     <center><h2>Contact Me</h2>
<form class="contact" action="a_test_mailer_processor.php" method="post">
<p>Name:</p> <!-- Can choose to customize form.html inputs starting here as needed, but be sure to reference any changes in mailer.php post fields-->
<input type="text" name="name" />
 <p>E-mail:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" />
<p>Subject:</p>
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<p>Message:</p>
<textarea name="message" syle="width: 45%; text-align: center;">Please leave a short message here</textarea></p>
<input class="send" type="submit" value="Send"> <!-- Send button-->
</form></center>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--end contact form-->
```

Here is the PHP I am trying to use

I updated the code as follows, swapping out my credentials and email address. No errors but still not working for me. Is there something else I can test?

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'MYSENDGRIDUSERNAME';
$pass = 'MYSENDGRIDPASSWORD';

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'MYEMAILADDRESS',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'MYEMAILADDRESS',
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

And here are the errors I am getting.
bool(true) 
Notice: Undefined variable: curl in D:\home\site\wwwroot\a_test_mailer_processor.php on line 36 Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\home\site\wwwroot\a_test_mailer_processor.php on line 36

I tried simply removing line 36, curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2); and the errors stopped but the form still did not get sent/received. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have found out the solution and have updated my answer. Please check and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you hadn’t defined `$curl` before setting parameters using `curl_setopt`, and here is a code sample on [SendGrid code examples page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html), please try it:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$pass = 'PASSWORD';

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'example@sendgrid.com',
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

---

### --Update--

If you get error message as **not defined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2**, we can directly set integer variable to `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`.
We can find details in http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php:

> One of CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6).

set as: `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);`

And I have to set an additional option :

`curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

so that I can succeed to set my request to SendGrid Server.

Comment: I updated my PHP as indicated in my question. I am still not recieving the emails.

Comment: Did your account succeed provisioning?

Comment: I think so. I have contacted their support and they have not said that I was not provisioned. Is there a way for me to know for sure?

Comment: Log in https://sendgrid.com/, there will be a hightlight bar telling you that your account failed provisioning if so.

Comment: I finally got it working. 

I put in your curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); and curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); and removed curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);


Thanks Gary!