# Can't get SendGrid PHP to work in my WebApp, can't even integrate it properly (maybe) with my App (resulting 500 internal server error)

Tags: php, asp.net, azure, sendgrid

I have ready order confirm script in HTML/PHP in Asp.net project (receipt.php) ready to mail to customer, but strangely can't manage to send it with Sendgrid no matter how hard I've tried.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
$data = $_SESSION['data']; 
$email = $data[email];
$first_name = $data[shipping_address][name];
$address1 = $data[shipping_address][address_line_1];
$zip = $data[shipping_address][zip];
$city = $data[shipping_address][city];


$messageaddr = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
                               <td align='left' valign='bottom' width='350'>
                                <font face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif' size='2'></font>
                            </td>
                            <td align='left' valign='bottom' width='250'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <hr>
                    <table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td valign='top'>
                                <p><font face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif' size='4'>Laskutusosoite</font></p>
                                <font face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif' size='2'>
                                    $first_name<br>
                                    <br>
                                    $address1<br>
                                    $zip $city<br>
                                    <br>
                                    Suomi<br>
                                    <a href='mailto: $email' target='_blank'>$email</a><br>
<div id=':nj' class='a3s' style='overflow: hidden;'><div class='adM'>
```

```
$namearr = $_POST["name"];
$imagearr = $_POST["image"];
$pricearr = $_POST["price"];
$quantityarr = $_POST["quantity"];
$totalcostarr = $_POST["totalcost"];

ob_start();

 for ($x = 0; $x <= $lenth-1; $x++) {
    echo "<td align='left' style='padding:10px 10px 10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;vertical-align:top'>
```

---

```
                               <td align='right' style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;vertical-align:top'><p><font face='Tahoma, arial, sans-serif' size='2'>$pricearr[$x]<br></font></p></td>
                                <td align='right' style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;vertical-align:top'><p><font face='Tahoma, arial, sans-serif' size='2'>$quantityarr[$x]<br></font></p></td>
                                <td align='right' style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;vertical-align:top'><p><font face='Tahoma, arial, sans-serif' size='2'>$totalcostarr[$x]<br></font></p></td>
                            </tr><tr>

$products = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();

$footermessage = "
                       </tr></tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:2px solid #000'>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:2px solid #000' align='right'><font face='Tahoma, arial, sans-serif' size='2'>Välisumma<br>Toimitus</font></td>
                                <td style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:2px solid #000'>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:2px solid #000' align='right'><font face='Tahoma, arial, sans-serif' size='2'>$subtotal<br>$shipping</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                                              style='padding:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #000'>&nbsp;</td>                                
    </tr>
</tbody>    
<tfoot>
";
$message = $messageaddr . ' ' . $products . ' ' . $footermessage; 
return $message;                
?>
```

I've tried with GitHub instructs https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php, added necessary 'requires' to composer.json-file etc., what else do I need on top these, except of course user and password?

No more lucky with instructions of Azure https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email/ ,I have composer, but no matter is it with SMTP API or Web Api, with Swift ends for same 500 server error, can't even managed to install for Web Api with Curl.

Sendgrid wizard  https://sendgrid.com/docs/Utilities/code_workshop.html  provided the whole  lib/vendor folders and several  probable essential files, but don't know, should  the whole package  include my Web api project or just necessary (sendgrid-php, autoload.php etc.) and  to which directory they needed to copy?

How on earth they call sendgrid easy(????) or maybe I still miss something essential? 
Would be grateful, if somebody could give yet another instructions for dummy , prefer with PHP-script, but with ASP.NET C# too, if that could be apply for this equally.

main.js posting the receipt;

```
            var xhr = $.post('receipt.php', { data: data, name: name, image: image, price: price, quantity: quantity, totalcost: totalcost, totals: basketCollection.totals , length: basketCollection.length }, function (data) {
                var data_from_ajax = data;
                console.log(data_from_ajax);
            });
```

Comment: The code included in your post seems incomplete. Have you run `composer install` ? Are you requiring `vendor/autoload.php` to use the composer lib ?

Comment: receipt.php script itself is tooo long to publish and don't think it's essential and I can see the whole receipt/html echoing nicely(with style/css), when debugging it. It's just missing the mailing script, that I'm waiting for. I put in 'composer.json'; "require": { "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~3.2" }, like instructed. Require'vendor/autoload.php ' seems to be there in 'sendgrid-php.php' -file, kiitos vaan! :)

Comment: It seems that the code snippet you provided has little relationship with sending email via sendgrid. You can try a simply test in PHP about sending email via sendgrid in you application. please refer [the answer in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723741/sendgrid-azure-php/32731776#32731776).

Comment: Thank's! Have to try with curl, although didn't get that work either. In command promt curl didn't even regognize my commands after reinstall it. Do I need enable it in PHP.ini everytime I reinstall it http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/.    Don't quite get that logig either, so it's Sendgrid is using curl and PHP is also depending it or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

After an hours of trying got it work! Main PHP-script was in a wrong directory related to the others in package.

Just sending dublicate emails mostly. Could it even cause from Sendgrid or just a local operator problem?